# Looking for a repertoire book on the Spanish with 5.d3 (4.d3 vs the Berlin)?

Tags: opening, books, 1.e4, ruy-lopez

Does anyone know of a good (or not so) repertoire book on the Spanish with 5.d3 vs the main line and 4.d3 vs the Berlin? Is there such a thing on the market? I've already got Andrew Martin's DVD The ABC of the Ruy Lopez, but still I'd like to have something to read on the subject, something that would be a bit more thorough, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Ruy Lopez: Move by Move](https://www.everymanchess.com/the-ruy-lopez-move-by-move) by Neil McDonald contains both a d3- and a main line repertoire against the Ruy Lopez.

Comment: Yes, it's probably the only option at the moment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [video series](https://chess24.com/en/learn/advanced/video/the-6-d3-spanish-according-to-svidler/introduction-to-the-6-d3-spanish) and [e-book](https://chess24.com/en/learn/advanced/ebook/the-6-d3-spanish-according-to-svidler) by GM Svidler on the Ruy Lopez with 6.d3. Although he considers the move order 5.0-0 Be7 6.d3, his analysis is probably also useful for you, as after 5.d3 Be7, the most popular and logical move is 6.0-0.

Comment: thank you. Sure, it could be useful, thought it allows Black to play the Open variation, which is not a big deal and it's relatively easy to study. But my initial idea with d3 was actually to delay castling as much as possible in order to perform the typical d2-f1-g3 knight maneuver without the rook being on f1 and after, let's say Be7 play c3. BTW after 5.d3 Bc5 is also strong and quite logical. And I believe that's exactly why Svidler propose to castle first and then play d3. He wants Black to play Be7 first to eliminate that Bc5 possibility.